# Django models: A List model with ordered Activities

Tags: python, django, database-design

I have a simple to-do list with activities that can be ordered by the user. I use the model *List*, with a many-to-many field to the model *Activities*.

Now I need a way to store the user defined ordering of the activities on the list. Should I go with an extra field in my List model to store the order of my activity primary keys like this:

```
class List(models.Model):
    activities = models.ManyToManyField(Activity)
    order = models.CommaSeperatedIntegerField(max_length=250)
```

Or should I go with a solution in the *Activity* model, like described here:
https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/998/

What method can be considered as best practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create your own ManyToMany Model defining the extra field `order`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships

something like:

```
class ActivityList(models.Model):
   activity = models.ForeignKey(Activity)
   list = models.ForeignKey(List)
   order = models.IntegerField()

class List(models.Model)
  activities = models.ManyToManyField(Activity, through='ActivityList')
```

**Now I need a way to store the user defined ordering of the activities on the list.**

Specifying and `order` field allows you to give each activity an order.

specifying a comma seperated string, is 100% not the way to go, IN fact it is one of the biggest anti patterns in relational databases, [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Using a `through` model lets you query for the order when presenting your todo list to the user

```
for activity in your_list.activities.all().order_by('order'):
   # display activity to user
```

Comment: I'm aware of that, and I'm actually already using a `through` for the activities. But why is that easier or better than a list field in the `List` model?

Comment: On a side note, is it correct to name one of the models `List`, since it is also a function?